# UISearchBar with separate delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm new to iOS programming and I need your help.
I am using UIsearchbar in our app but i want to separate the delegate of it. 
I want to see the Nslog that i declare everytime I typed but it's returning an error :(
Heres my code.

//HomeController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
@interface HomeController : UIViewController< UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

//HomeController.m

```
SearchBarDelegate *searchDelegate = [[SearchBarDelegate alloc]init];
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44)];

searchBar.placeholder = @"Search here";
searchBar.layer.zPosition = 1000;
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];
searchBar setDelegate:searchDelegate];
```

//SearchBarDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchBarDelegate : UISearchBar<UISearchBarDelegate>

@end
```

//SearchBarDelegate.m

```
#import "SearchBarDelegate.h"

@implementation SearchBarDelegate

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBars //Clicked the box
{
    searchBars.showsCancelButton = YES;

}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBars //hides searchBar and keyboard
{
    searchBars.showsCancelButton = NO;
    [searchBars resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBars  //search button in keyboard
{
    [searchBars resignFirstResponder];
}


- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBars textDidChange:(NSString*)searchText //while typing
{
    NSLog(@"Typing... -> %@",searchBars.text);
}


@end
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: This is the error message: (lldb)